# How to find inversion pairs in an array and their index positions?

Tags: c++, fenwick-tree

I find difficult to find the inversion pairs in the array. I got the number of inversion pairs in the array but the logic seems so complex that I can't able to list pairs. I am new to C++, any help is appreciated.

```
 Example:
 Input:  arr[] = {8, 4, 2, 1}
 Output: 6
```

Expecting this output

Given array has six inversions (8,4) and index(0,1), (4,2) and index(1,2),
 (8,2) and index(0,2), (8,1) and index(0,3), (4,1) and index(1,3), (2,1) and index(2,4)

```
// C++ program to count inversions using Binary Indexed Tree 
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// Returns sum of arr[0..index]. This function assumes 
// that the array is preprocessed and partial sums of 
// array elements are stored in BITree[]. 
int getSum(int BITree[], int index) 
{ 
    int sum = 0; // Initialize result 

    // Traverse ancestors of BITree[index] 
    while (index > 0) 
    { 
        // Add current element of BITree to sum 
        sum += BITree[index]; 

        // Move index to parent node in getSum View 
        index -= index & (-index); 
    } 
    return sum; 
} 

// Updates a node in Binary Index Tree (BITree) at given index 
// in BITree. The given value 'val' is added to BITree[i] and 
// all of its ancestors in tree. 
void updateBIT(int BITree[], int n, int index, int val) 
{ 
    // Traverse all ancestors and add 'val' 
    while (index <= n) 
    { 
    // Add 'val' to current node of BI Tree 
    BITree[index] += val; 

    // Update index to that of parent in update View 
    index += index & (-index); 
    } 
} 

// Returns inversion count arr[0..n-1] 
int getInvCount(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int invcount = 0; // Initialize result 

    // Find maximum element in arr[] 
    int maxElement = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        if (maxElement < arr[i]) 
            maxElement = arr[i]; 

    // Create a BIT with size equal to maxElement+1 (Extra 
    // one is used so that elements can be directly be 
    // used as index) 
    int BIT[maxElement+1]; 
    for (int i=1; i<=maxElement; i++) 
        BIT[i] = 0; 

    // Traverse all elements from right. 
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) 
    { 
        // Get count of elements smaller than arr[i] 
        invcount += getSum(BIT, arr[i]-1); 

        // Add current element to BIT 
        updateBIT(BIT, maxElement, arr[i], 1); 
    } 

    return invcount; 
} 

// Driver program 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {8, 4, 2, 1}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); 
    cout << "Number of inversions are : " << getInvCount(arr,n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The program creates new array BITree[] that makes it more complex. How the position of the element is found.

Comment: What is "inversion pair" in this context?

Comment: You are given an array A[] consisting of N elements. The inversion count of an array is defined as the number of (i,j) pairs such that i <j and A[i]> A[j]